# Refresh token in Google client ID

Tags: google-oauth, google-ads-api, refresh-token, clientid, oauth2-playground

1. Does anybody know after how much time or how many requests does refresh token expires in Google ads API? I created refresh token here https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground.
2. Does anyone know what is the impersonated email in server account in Google ads API? I created server account in Google cloud project. If I run python code with Service Account configuration with generated *json_key_file_path* and same *impersonated_email* as my email account with which I created project then I get an error `google.auth.exceptions.RefreshError: ('unauthorized_client: Client is unauthorized to retrieve access tokens using this method, or client not authorized for any of the scopes requested.', {'error': 'unauthorized_client', 'error_description': 'Client is unauthorized to retrieve access tokens using this method, or client not authorized for any of the scopes requested.'})`. If I put for *impersonated_email* *client_email* that I got from generated jon file I get an error: `User in the cookie is not a valid Ads user.`

Answer (score 0):

> Client is unauthorized to retrieve access tokens using this method, or client not authorized for any of the scopes requested.

Is a common error message.  There are serval types of clients in Google developer console that you can create

1. installed
2. web
3. native
4. service account.
5. mobile

The coded needed to authorize these different types of authorization methods is also different.

The [Oauth playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground) by default uses web app credentials. You can add your own web credentials in there and create a token for your own system.  But this is only used for testing.

You cant though use a token created via playground in code used for an android application, its the wrong type of authorization flow.  You will need to crate your own mobile credentials and authorize though your application.